# Briefcase configuration error: Configuration file not found

Tags: python, beeware

my environment is win11 and conda/python3.8
I use `briefcase new` to create a new project,all options are default.

[image]

but the project report an error "Briefcase configuration error: Configuration file not found.

Did you run Briefcase in a project directory that contains 'pyproject.toml'?" when I use `briefcase dev`

[image]

my pip list:

```
absl-py                       1.4.0
aes                           1.2.0
alabaster                     0.7.13
anyio                         4.0.0
argon2-cffi                   23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arrow                         1.2.3
asgiref                       3.5.2
asttokens                     2.0.5
astunparse                    1.6.3
async-lru                     2.0.4
atomicwrites                  1.4.1
attrs                         23.1.0
Babel                         2.12.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.12.2
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         23.9.1
bleach                        6.0.0
Bottleneck                    1.3.5
briefcase                     0.3.16
Brotli                        1.0.9
brotlipy                      0.7.0
build                         1.0.3
cachetools                    5.3.1
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       3.0.4
charset-normalizer            2.1.1
click                         8.1.7
cloudpickle                   2.0.0
clr-loader                    0.2.6
colorama                      0.4.6
comm                          0.1.4
contourpy                     1.0.5
cookiecutter                  2.4.0
cryptography                  38.0.4
curio                         1.6
cycler                        0.11.0
debugpy                       1.5.1
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
docrepr                       0.2.0
docutils                      0.18.1
EasyProcess                   1.1
entrypoint2                   1.1
entrypoints                   0.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
exceptiongroup                1.1.3
executing                     0.8.3
fastjsonschema                2.18.0
filelock                      3.9.0
Flask                         2.2.5
flatbuffers                   23.5.26
flit_core                     3.6.0
fonttools                     4.25.0
fqdn                          1.5.1
freegames                     2.5.3
gast                          0.4.0
gitdb                         4.0.11
GitPython                     3.1.40
google-auth                   1.4.2
google-auth-oauthlib          1.0.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
grpcio                        1.57.0
h11                           0.14.0
h2                            4.1.0
h5py                          3.9.0
hpack                         4.0.0
hyperframe                    6.0.1
idna                          2.8
imageio                       2.31.5
imagesize                     1.4.1
importlib-metadata            6.8.0
importlib-resources           5.2.0
iniconfig                     2.0.0
ipykernel                     6.19.2
ipyparallel                   8.6.1
ipython                       8.15.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    8.1.1
isoduration                   20.11.0
itsdangerous                  2.1.2
jedi                          0.18.1
Jinja2                        3.1.2
joblib                        1.3.1
json5                         0.9.14
jsonpointer                   2.4
jsonschema                    4.19.1
jsonschema-specifications     2023.7.1
jupyter_client                8.3.1
jupyter_core                  5.2.0
jupyter-events                0.7.0
jupyter-lsp                   2.2.0
jupyter_server                2.7.3
jupyter_server_terminals      0.4.4
jupyterlab                    4.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab_server             2.25.0
jupyterlab-widgets            3.0.9
kaitaistruct                  0.10
keras                         2.13.1
keyboard                      0.13.5
Kivy                          2.2.1
kivy-deps.angle               0.3.3
kivy-deps.glew                0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2                0.6.0
Kivy-Garden                   0.1.5
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
lazy_loader                   0.3
ldap3                         2.9.1
libclang                      16.0.6
Markdown                      3.4.4
markdown-it-py                3.0.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.1
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mdurl                         0.1.2
mistune                       3.0.1
mitmproxy                     9.0.1
mitmproxy_wireguard           0.1.23
mkl-fft                       1.3.1
mkl-random                    1.2.2
mkl-service                   2.4.0
MouseInfo                     0.1.3
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.7
mss                           9.0.1
munkres                       1.1.4
mypy-extensions               1.0.0
Naked                         0.1.32
nbclient                      0.8.0
nbconvert                     7.8.0
nbformat                      5.9.2
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      2.8.4
notebook                      7.0.4
notebook_shim                 0.2.3
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.23.5
oauthlib                      3.2.2
opencv-python                 4.8.1.78
openpyxl                      3.1.2
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
outcome                       1.2.0
overrides                     7.4.0
packaging                     23.0
pandas                        1.5.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
parso                         0.8.3
passlib                       1.7.4
pathspec                      0.11.2
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.4.0
pip                           23.3.1
platformdirs                  3.11.0
pluggy                        1.3.0
ply                           3.11
portpicker                    1.2.0
prometheus-client             0.17.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.36
protobuf                      4.24.0
psutil                        5.9.0
publicsuffix2                 2.20191221
pure-eval                     0.2.2
py                            1.11.0
pyasn1                        0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                0.3.0
PyAudio                       0.2.13
PyAutoGUI                     0.9.54
pycparser                     2.21
pycryptodome                  3.19.0
pydivert                      2.1.0
pydub                         0.25.1
pygame                        2.5.2
PyGetWindow                   0.0.9
Pygments                      2.16.1
PyMsgBox                      1.0.9
pynput                        1.7.6
pyOpenSSL                     22.1.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
pyperclip                     1.8.2
pypiwin32                     223
pyproject_hooks               1.0.0
PyQt5                         5.15.7
PyQt5-sip                     12.11.0
PyRect                        0.2.0
pyscreenshot                  3.1
PyScreeze                     0.1.29
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytest                        6.2.5
pytest-asyncio                0.20.3
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-json-logger            2.0.7
python-slugify                8.0.1
pythonnet                     3.0.3
pytweening                    1.0.7
pytz                          2022.7
pywin32                       305.1
pywinpty                      2.0.11
PyYAML                        6.0.1
pyzmq                         25.1.1
qtconsole                     5.4.4
QtPy                          2.4.0
referencing                   0.30.2
requests                      2.28.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
rfc3339-validator             0.1.4
rfc3986-validator             0.1.1
rich                          13.6.0
rpds-py                       0.10.3
rsa                           4.9
ruamel.yaml                   0.17.35
ruamel.yaml.clib              0.2.8
scikit-image                  0.22.0
scikit-learn                  1.3.0
scipy                         1.11.1
Send2Trash                    1.8.2
setuptools                    68.2.2
shellescape                   3.8.1
simplegeneric                 0.8.1
sip                           6.6.2
six                           1.12.0
smmap                         5.0.1
sniffio                       1.3.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.5
Sphinx                        7.2.6
sphinx-rtd-theme              1.3.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.7
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.4
sphinxcontrib-jquery          4.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.6
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.9
spyder-kernels                2.1.3
stack-data                    0.2.0
sympy                         1.11.1
tensorboard                   2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.1
tensorflow                    2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.13.0
tensorflow-intel              2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.31.0
termcolor                     2.3.0
terminado                     0.17.1
testpath                      0.6.0
text-unidecode                1.3
threadpoolctl                 3.2.0
tifffile                      2023.9.26
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toga                          0.3.1
toga-core                     0.3.1
toga-winforms                 0.3.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
tomli_w                       1.0.0
torch                         2.0.0
torchaudio                    2.0.0
torchvision                   0.15.0
tornado                       6.3.3
tqdm                          4.66.1
traitlets                     5.7.1
travertino                    0.3.0
trio                          0.22.2
typing_extensions             4.4.0
uri-template                  1.3.0
urllib3                       1.24.3
urwid                         2.1.2
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webcolors                     1.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.6.3
Werkzeug                      2.3.6
wheel                         0.41.3
widgetsnbextension            4.0.9
win-inet-pton                 1.1.0
wincertstore                  0.2
wrapt                         1.15.0
wsproto                       1.2.0
zipp                          3.11.0
zstandard                     0.19.0
```

---

thank you !!!

I tried this [this github issue](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/553),but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pyproject.toml` was created in a directory called `helloworld`.

**As `briefcase`'s output is telling you**, you need to `cd helloworld` (that is to say, your current working directory needs to be `C:\Androi_test\helloworld`) before you can run any commands that expect to be inside the project directory.